# useState - Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I got this infinite loop error. I want to change the state of `isDisabled` based on the value of `count`. How should I solve this, if I want to keep the state in hook?

```
const TheGame = () => { 
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);

  const onHitHandler = async () => {
    let card = await fetchCard();

    if (card[0].value === 'ACE')
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 11);
    else if (card[0].value === 'JACK' || card[0].value === 'QUEEN') || card[0].value === 'KING')
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 10);
    else
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + Number(card[0].value));
  };

  if(count > 21)
    setIsDisabled(true);  // error occures here.

  return(something);
};
```

Comment: How is `count` set? Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Use a `useEffect` hook on `count` instead. It will only be triggered when `count` changes, without creating an infinite loop like your current example.

Comment: I've edited the post, so you can see how I'm changing the `count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(count > 21) {
    setIsDisabled(true); 
  }
}, [count])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a useEffect, an alternative approach is to realize that this variable is not necessarily intrinsic state, but something that can be "computed" from the intrinsic state.

For example, your code could say

```
const TheGame = () => { 
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const onHitHandler = async () => {
    let card = await fetchCard();

    if (card[0].value === 'ACE')
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 11);
    else if (card[0].value === 'JACK' || card[0].value === 'QUEEN') || card[0].value === 'KING')
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 10);
    else
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + Number(card[0].value));
  };

  const disabled = count > 21 ? true : false // or simply const disabled = count>21

  return disabled ? <DisabledState/> : <NonDisabledState/>
};
```

Also, the reason why it fails when in the previous case is you do not want to use a "setState" type callback inside the normal "rendering" of your component. That is because any time a setState callback is used, it will produce a re-render of your component (so that the new state can be drawn on the screen!)